# Commuting matrices and simultaneous diagonalizability

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, representation-theory

It is a known fact from linear algebra that if a set of matrices is pairwise commutable then they are simultaneously diagonalizable. A problem in the book I am currently studying asks to prove this claim using representation theory. Specifically

If $G = \{M_1,\ldots,M_k\}$ is an abelian subgroup of $\rm{GL}_d(\mathbb{C}).$ How can one use representation theory to show that the matrices in $G$ are simultaneously diagonalizable?

Comment: Could you be more specific: which type of representation theory are referring to?

Comment: I'm guessing you want to assume that each $M_i$ itself is diagonalizable?

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis By a group representation I mean a homomorphism from $G$ to $GL_d$

Comment: @EricO.Korman I think what (the author) meant was the existence of an invertible matrix $T$ such that $TMT^{-1}$ l is diagonal for any $M \in G.$

Comment: As stated the result is false. you need to assume that for each $M_i$ there is some $T_i$ such that $T_i M_i T_i^{-1}$ is diagonal.  Then the question should be to show that one can choose $T_i$ to be the same across $i$.

Comment: @EricO.Korman That assumption is not necessary for the problem posed, because it asserts a finite subgroup of $GL$. For the first problem stated, however, that assumption is needed.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein you're right.  For some reason I was thinking that $G$ was an abelian group generated by those matrices, not necessarily equal to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more linear algebra than representation theory. One proof is to notice that all matrices $g$ in a finite subgroup $G$ of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\Bbb C)$ are diagonalisable, for if $m$ is the order of $G$, then $$g^m=\mathrm{id}.$$
That is, all elements of $G$ have a annihiliating polynomial with only simple roots, $X^m-1$. If $G$ is abelian, then te result you quoted shows that they are simultaneously diagonalisable.

If you want to use "representation theory", you could invoke the fact that all irreducible complex representations of an abelian group are one dimensional, and complete reducibility of complex representations of finite groups. But this is a corollary of the result above (the abelian part is.) The first paragraph of my answer is indeed the proof of this fact for abelian groups.