# Simultaneous diagonalisable matrices

Tags: representation-theory

I am well aware that there are already several questions and posts regarding the following topic. However, I could not find any answer to the following problem in Bruce Sagan's book *The Symmetric Group*:

Let $\left\{X_1,X_2,...X_n\right\} \subseteq GL_d$ be a subgroup of commuting matrices. Show that these matrices are simultaneously diagonalisable using representation theory.

> Two $n$ x $n$ matrices $A, B$ are said to be simultaneously
>   diagonalizable if there is an invertible matrix $S$ such that both
>   $S^{-1}AS$ and $S^{-1}BS$ are diagonal matrices.

I have already read the question [Commuting matrices and simultaneous diagonalizability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643742/commuting-matrices-and-simultaneous-diagonalizability) and all the other posts I could find, but I think that a proof should involve Schur's Lemma, as is hinted by Proposition 2.8 on page 5 in [these lecture notes](http://math.berkeley.edu/~teleman/math/RepThry.pdf).

Do you know how to find an answer to this problem?

I am sorry that I could not yet find an answer on how to prove this!

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert in representation theory but believe that over complex numbers, the main idea goes as follows. The matrices form a commutative subgroup $G$ of $GL$. Any irreducible subrepresentation of the defining representation $\mathbb{C}^d$ of $G$ is one-dimensional (the action of any $X_i$ is $G$-invariant, so it acts as a scalar by Schur theorem), so an irreducible subrepresentation generates a common eigenvector to all your matrices. Now $G$ is finite, hence the representation $\mathbb{C}^d$ is completely reducible and you can find a $G$-invariant complement (and, by induction, further eigenvectors common to all matrices).

Note, however, that the result would not be true if $G=\{X_1, \ldots, X_n\}$ were not a group (the counterexample being $X_i=\begin{pmatrix}1 & i\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ for $i=1,2$).

Comment: It is true if {X_1,...,X_n} are all diagonalizable, even if they don't form a group.

Comment: @AlexZorn I believe so, but can't see a formal reason at this moment..

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! There is one thing I do not understand: What is the defining representation $\mathbb{C}^d$ of $G$? I have only heard about the defining representation of the symmetric group $S_n$, but I do not know what the defining representation of an arbitrary group $G$ is.

Comment: Elements of $G$ are matrices $d\times d$, right? So they act on $\mathbb{C}^d$ :)

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, now that I know it, it seems pretty obvious that it is just the $d \times d$ matrices should be acting on $\mathbb{C}$.

Is this always the meaning of *defining representation*? Is the *defining representation* always the "natural" representation that is obvious from the context (like $S_n$ on the integers $1, ..., n$)?

Thank you for the guide to the proof, I think I have now got it:

Let $(v_1,v_2,...v_d)$ be a basis for $\mathbb{C}^d$. As $G$ is abelian, all its irreducible representations are one-dimensional.

Comment: This is proved in Corollary 1, http://www.math.columbia.edu/~woit/RepThy/repthynotes2.pdf.

Hence, each basis vector is in one of the $d$ irreducible submodules of $\mathbb{C}^d$. Hence there are $d$ linearly independent eigenvectors that are shared by all matrices $X_i$.

By letting $S = (v_1 v_2 ... v_d)$, where the $v_i$s are column vectors, we have found a matrix $S$ which simultaneously diagonalises each $X_i$, as required.