# Prove two commute, diagonalizable matrices have the some diagonalizing matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\ M \in \mathbb M_{n\times n} $ be a finite group of diagonalizable matrices that each two are commuting ($\ AB = BA $ ), I need to prove that there exists a $\ P $ matrix that will diagonalize any matrix in $\ M $

I can't intuitively understand why it is true, and can't really think of a way to prove it. If I understand correctly, according to this [paper](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/%7Emisha/Fall08/19.pdf) it is just called Schur lemma?
I've found many questions about opposite direction (if they diagonalizable then they commute)

Comment: The key thing you want to prove is the fact that if two matrices commute, then one stabilizes the proper subspaces of the other one. Then, start with diagonalizing one of your matrices, and then look at the restrictions of your matrices to the proper subspaces of this matrix, then reiterate the process in each of these subspaces . You will end up with a decomposition of the space into a direct sum of subspaces on which all your matrices act as homotheties.

Comment: @J.Darné Thanks! can you maybe explain what does "one stabilizes the proper subspaces of the other one" mean ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant eigenspaces (in French, they are called "sous-espaces propres", and my literal translation was unfortunate).

Comment: assuming we are working over $\mathbb C$ (or at least a field of characteristic zero), I think OP is looking for a basic group representation explanation... but @bm1125 have you studied representation theory at all?

Answer (score 1):

This is a classical result, so you can find a proof in any course on reduction of endomorphism. See for instance theorem 5.11 in:
[https://pub.math.leidenuniv.nl/~luijkrmvan/linalg2/2018/LinAlg2-2018.pdf](https://pub.math.leidenuniv.nl/%7Eluijkrmvan/linalg2/2018/LinAlg2-2018.pdf)
(which is the first one I found).

NB1 : If you are looking at a finite subgroup $G$ of $Gl_n(\mathbb C)$, the matrices in $G$ are automatically diagonalizable, since they have finite order. See [Commuting matrices and simultaneous diagonalizability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643742/commuting-matrices-and-simultaneous-diagonalizability)

NB2 : Over $\mathbb C$, you can see it as a consequence of Schur's Lemma, but in a contorted way. Namely, Schur's Lemma says that over an algebraically closed field, the only endomorphisms of an irreducible representation $V$ of a group $G$ are homotheties. If your group is abelian, then the action $g \cdot -$ of an element $g \in G$ gives an endomorphism of $V$, so $g$ acts as an homothety, hence any subspace of $V$ is stable by any $g$, and $V$ must be of dimension $1$ (else it would not be irreducible). If your group is finite, any representation is a direct sum of irreducible representations. So, if $G$ is abelian and finite, any representation is a direct sum of stable lines, and a basis adapted to this decomposition is a co-diagonalization basis for the action of $G$.

Comment: Maschke's theorem is key here so something about $\text{char}\big(\mathbb F\big)$ is needed.  But the assumption that $\mathbb F$ is algebraically closed can be dropped since all matrices in the finite group are stated to be diagonalizable.

Comment: Well, if you suppose that your matrices are diagonalizable in the first place (which I do not suppose in the NBs), the language of representation theory is really not useful. One way or the other, you end up doing exactly  the linear algebraic reasoning I am referring to, which is true over any field, whereas representation theory depends strongly on the field you choose.